Compile a script, add it to system so it runs before (or during) system boot
I really don't know how to go about this so I'm asking you guys here for help
Long story short with some background details
I have a USB3 2.5gb NIC attached to my Raspberry Pi 5 (this SBC also has its own built in 1gb NIC). I have installed the OS Raspberry Pi OS Lite 64bit Debian version: 12 (bookworm) - yes everything is updated.
Network and NIC are configured here is the details/post

I want to only use the USB3 NIC as my main/default interface

The problem;
After each boot/reboot (ofc even shutdown and boot) I have to physically disconnect the USB3 NIC by removing it and then attaching it again.
Searching around the internet I have found/ran into some posts which suggest some commands that I would guess one could pile up into one script and run.
Ubuntu, superuser and this article over at GeekLand which goes into it all in length use google translate or something since this is written in Spanish.
My question is;
Would someone be kind enough and explain how I could execute and apply this to my system in a more permanent way.
My end goal is; To influence my systems boot-script in someway so the .sh script containing the code for disconnecting and reconnecting the USB3 NIC (if that even is the best solution) would run before the boot-script In my logical thinking that would solve the problem I have ran into which seems to be some kind of Kernel issue. Also there is an error during boot I need to get rid of.
I would also kindly ask for help on the compiling of it since my knowledge around this all is very limited and this is basically a scary part since it would mess around with system boot.
Here is the outputs I think is required in order to write such script:
sudo lsusb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

sudo lsusb -t

/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci-hcd/1p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci-hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci-hcd/1p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci-hcd/2p, 480M

ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 14:24 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/axi/1000120000.pcie/1f00200000.usb/xhci-hcd.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 14:24 2-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/axi/1000120000.pcie/1f00200000.usb/xhci-hcd.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 14:24 2-1 -> ../../../devices/platform/axi/1000120000.pcie/1f00200000.usb/xhci-hcd.0/usb2/2-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 14:24 2-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/axi/1000120000.pcie/1f00200000.usb/xhci-hcd.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 14:24 3-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/axi/1000120000.pcie/1f00300000.usb/xhci-hcd.1/usb3/3-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 14:24 4-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/axi/1000120000.pcie/1f00300000.usb/xhci-hcd.1/usb4/4-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 14:24 usb1 -> ../../../devices/platform/axi/1000120000.pcie/1f00200000.usb/xhci-hcd.0/usb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 14:24 usb2 -> ../../../devices/platform/axi/1000120000.pcie/1f00200000.usb/xhci-hcd.0/usb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 14:24 usb3 -> ../../../devices/platform/axi/1000120000.pcie/1f00300000.usb/xhci-hcd.1/usb3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 14:24 usb4 -> ../../../devices/platform/axi/1000120000.pcie/1f00300000.usb/xhci-hcd.1/usb4

lsusb -v

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.20
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0x8156
  bcdDevice           31.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
  iSerial                 6 001000001
  bNumConfigurations      3
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0039
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              256mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval              11
        bMaxBurst               0
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0068
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     2
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              256mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass     13
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              5
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1
      CDC Ethernet:
        iMacAddress                      3 (??)
        bmEthernetStatistics    0x0031501f
        wMaxSegmentSize               1518
        wNumberMCFilters            0x8000
        bNumberPowerFilters              0
      CDC NCM:
        bcdNcmVersion        1.00
        bmNetworkCapabilities 0x2b
          8-byte ntb input size
          max datagram size
          net address
          packet filter
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval              11
        bMaxBurst               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      1
      iInterface              0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      1
      iInterface              4
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0062
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     3
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              256mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 Ethernet Networking
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              5
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1
      CDC Ethernet:
        iMacAddress                      3 (??)
        bmEthernetStatistics    0x0031501f
        wMaxSegmentSize               1518
        wNumberMCFilters            0x8000
        bNumberPowerFilters              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval              11
        bMaxBurst               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              4
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3

Update: putting the outputs here which where asked for in the comments
ls -1 /etc/systemd/network/
73-usb-net-by-mac.link
99-default.link
eth0.network
eth1.network
lo.network
---------------------------------------------
/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0
Type=ether

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[DHCPv4]
RouteMetric=100
---------------------------------------------
/etc/systemd/network/eth1.network
[Match]
Name=eth1
Type=ether

[Address]
Address=10.0.0.10/24
Broadcast=true
RouteMetric=10

[Network]
DHCP=no
DNS=1.1.1.1

[Route]
Gateway=10.0.0.1
Metric=10
---------------------------------------------
ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:cf:67:2f:cf:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:27:88:29:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
---------------------------------------------
ip r
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 10
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.10 metric 10

Here is the log for the service error during boot
systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
× systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-04-30 11:14:08 CEST; 24min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8)
    Process: 416 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 416 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 9ms

Apr 30 11:12:07 Pi5 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured...
Apr 30 11:14:08 Pi5 systemd-networkd-wait-online[416]: Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity.
Apr 30 11:14:08 Pi5 systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 30 11:14:08 Pi5 systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 30 11:14:08 Pi5 systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured.

This is the output during boot up
[FAILED] Failed to start systemd-networkd-wait-online.service Wait for Network to be Configured.
See 'systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online.service' for details.


Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For more details about the first step around my solution regarding the problems check here
Now The solution
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y
git config --global user.name "YourGitHudUserName"
git config --global user.email "YourRegisterdEmailAdressOnGitHudAccount"
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
sudo git clone https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl
cd uhubctl
sudo make
sudo make install

and then
I decided to check and see when I would archive UP status for eth1 so I constructed this code and reviewed it outputs, pin pointed which power cycle for the 4 ports was the correct one, however the code in the end cycles all of my USB ports since Pi5 design is what it is.. (read all the details in the link above!)
ip a > status_before_uhubctl.txt
sudo uhubctl -l 1 -a 0 > output_of_uhubctl.txt
ip a > status_after_uhubctl.txt

Here are the loggs
status_before_uhubctl.txt
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen>
    link/ether 2c:cf:67:2f:cf:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

output_of_uhubctl.txt
Current status for hub 2 [1d6b:0003 Linux 6.6.28+rpt-rpi-2712 xhci-hcd xHCI Host Controller xhci-hcd>
  Port 1: 0203 power 5gbps U0 enable connect [0bda:8151 Realtek USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN 001000001]
Sent power off request
New status for hub 2 [1d6b:0003 Linux 6.6.28+rpt-rpi-2712 xhci-hcd xHCI Host Controller xhci-hcd.0, >
  Port 1: 0080 off
Current status for hub 1 [1d6b:0002 Linux 6.6.28+rpt-rpi-2712 xhci-hcd xHCI Host Controller xhci-hcd>
  Port 1: 0100 power
  Port 2: 0103 power enable connect [0b05:1a07 ASUSTeK ROG STRIX SCOPE RX TKL WIRELESS DELUXE]
Sent power off request
New status for hub 1 [1d6b:0002 Linux 6.6.28+rpt-rpi-2712 xhci-hcd xHCI Host Controller xhci-hcd.0, >
  Port 1: 0000 off
  Port 2: 0000 off

status_after_uhubctl.txt
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:cf:67:2f:cf:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:27:88:29:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.10/24 metric 10 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd75:a6e1:4b04:360:224:27ff:fe88:2917/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 1758sec preferred_lft 1758sec
    inet6 fe80::224:27ff:fe88:2917/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

My eth1 now has UP status, which means I did not have to physically remove the NIC and reattach it again.
And here is the details around the .service I created so the USB ports would get the very much needed power-cycle.
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/usb_power_cycle.service

[Unit]
Description=Power Cycle for USB ports

[Service]
ExecStart=uhubctl -l 1 -a 0 ; uhubctl -l 3 -a 0 ; uhubctl -l 1 -a 1 ; uhubctl -l 3 -a 1
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

sudo systemctl enable usb_power_cycle.service

sudo reboot now

So, now I don't need to disconnected the (NIC) device and reconnect it again after each and every reboot regardless of it being cold or warm boot. The NIC, SBC and the OS seem to work in some kind of symbiosis.
And lastley, to get rid of the error message during boot up. This approach may not be the best I know but it will solve the "Failed to start systemd-networkd-wait-online.service" once and for all.
I basically had to make sure the service wouldn't wait for something that would never occur since I don't use the built in NIC (eth0 getting link) of this SBC, so..
I added following to the .network for which NIC I'll not use
[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no
[Match]
Name=eth0
Type=ether

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[DHCPv4]
RouteMetric=100

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no

A special thank you for all whom have been involved and contributed in the comments and so on, without your help this outcome would not have been possible - you are incredible people!
Ps, the scope if all this started initially in this post and that let me into making this post here so if you are interested check it out.

The output of your lsusb shows:
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN

Look at the output of:
ls -1ong /sys/bus/usb/devices/

The path /sys/devices/pci000:00/* refers to the devices on the PCI system bus. (Motherboard data travels on a designated path called a 'bus')
Sysfs is a virtual filesystem used by the kernel. Information about devices and drivers, and some, modifiable, for configuration and control of devices attached to the system.

Update: Not trying to overwhelm, but this is a breakdown. Also, has mention of journalctl and others I mentioned below.
Service file sections:

[Unit]: This section contains general information about the service, like its description and dependencies.
[Service]: This section defines how the service is executed, including the executable to run, user privileges, working directory, and restart behavior.
[Install]: This section (optional) is used if you want systemd to automatically enable and disable the service during system startup/shutdown.

I wouldn't have felt good about posting all this yesterday.It's all so intimidating already.

[Unit]
Description=Reset usb2 on startup

[Service]
ExecStart=bash -c "echo '0' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/autosuspend_delay_ms" && bash -c "echo 'auto' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/control
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Create a .service file. Copy the above text and run the following:
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/usb_reset.service

Now, paste the text into nano.Save it and exit. (Ctrl+S > Y > Enter > Ctrl+X)
Now, run these two commands.
Initialize the new .service file & start the service.
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable usb_reset.service

Done! This will now run the ExecStart= command from the .service file, resetting usb2 each startup, automatically.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@terdon I would never let that happen. Is there a way to suggest a chat session?  It doesn't offer it until 26 messages in, so it's impossible to avoid.

Yeah, the system is far from perfect... It will suggest it quite soon actually, long before 26, but it counts the number of messages between specific users. So if there are multiple people, it might indeed take a while to appear. Now, you can always open a chat room manually and invite folks over, but that can be cumbersome. You can also try flagging for mod attention and asking us to move to chat. But really, don't worry about it. The above is an auto-generated comment and might come across as a bit aggressive, but you didn't do anything wrong, I just moved the comments.
